# ¿Cómo detectar si mi código se ejecuta en Node.js pero no en un navegador sin usar new Function()?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

[Esta respuesta (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31090240/13860) explica cómo saber si tu JavaScript se está ejecutando en Node.js o en el navegador, pero depende del uso de `new Function()`, que no funciona en un navegador si usas un CSP sin `unsafe-eval` (y eso es importante en mi proyecto).

Yo sé que hay varias formas sensibles, pero falibles también como puede ser ver si `window` o `process.versions.node` están definidos pero es fácil definir estas variables para engañar al programa.

¿Hay alguna otra forma que sea infalible de detectar si estoy en el navegador o en Node.js sin usar `new Function()`?

Supongo que por lo menos puedo intentar eso en un `try {}` y, si estoy en Node.js, puedo estar con certeza, y si no puedo usar una forma menos infalible.

Comment: have u tried browserify? http://browserify.org/ ( i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038483/how-to-detect-when-browserify-is-being-run )

Comment: Cuando usas `Function` el valor de `this` siempre apunta al scope global pero si haces una llamada a una funcion normal usando el binding por defecto también apuntará al scope global si no esta ejecutándose en "modo estricto" asi que si no controlas los scripts que se ejecutan en tu entorno esta forma tampoco te sirve

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro: Sí, estoy usando browserify. Pero no resuelve esta pregunta.

Comment: Pues usaría un método que usa una biblioteca especifica para Node.js. Ej. [child_process](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.10.x/api/child_process.html) o [FS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.10.x/api/fs.html#fs_file_system). Con estas bibliotecas puede hacer una serie de pruebas que es difícil engañar: crear un fichero y después leerlo, ejecutar un proceso y enviarle una señal et cetera.

Comment: @user3159253: Es fácil crear un objeto se llama "child_process" en el navegador, también... Por eso la pregunta.

Comment: No, por supuesto, es fácil crear un objeto. ¿Pero cómo crear un _comportamiento_ completo, especifico para un proceso, un archivo y así?

Comment: Por cierto, si ladra como un perro, corre como un perro, y colea como un perro, es perro :)

Comment: ¿Qué es su objetivo preciso?

Comment: @user3159253: Es fácil, y a veces muy útil, crear un objeto con comportamiento completo... se llama un Mock, y existen muchas bibliotecas para hacerlo para varías razones. (Son muy común para probar códigos, pero existen para otras cosas también). Y si estoy escribiendo una biblioteca, no quiero divinar si algo está un mock (por razonas válidas, o maliciosas).  Solo quiero saber "la verdad" del entorno de ejecución.

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Por favor, no escribas comentarios en inglés, este sitio es 100% en español.

Answer (score 3):

Hay una solución basándose en `localStorage` (que transforma los enteros almacenados en "strings"). No encontré una manera de trampear la detección desde node porque no se puede atrapar el agregado de una clave que no se sabe cuál será.

La función `isDOM` devuelve `true` en un navegador (que soporte `localStorage` o sea todos los modernos) y devuelve `false` en node.js

```
function isDOM(){
    try{
        var key;
        while(localStorage[key='detect-dom-'+Math.random()]) ;
        localStorage[key]=1;
        return localStorage[key]!==1;
    }catch(err){
        return false;
    }
}

console.log('isDOM', isDOM());

if(!isDOM()){
    global.localStorage=[];
    Object.observe(global.localStorage, function(changes){
        changes.forEach(function(change){
            if(typeof change.object[change.name] != "string" && change.name=='add' || change.name=='update'){
                change.object[change.name] = ""+change.object[change.name];
            }
            console.log(change, JSON.stringify(change.object[change.name]));
        });
    });
}

console.log('cheat isDOM', isDOM());
```

El intento de trampear es con `Object.observe` pero al ser asincrónico no funciona. Quizás se pueda trampear en un futuro con `Proxy` [(en Mozilla)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) pero en node 4 no anda

---

*mi respuesta anterior basándome en la idea señalada:*

Hay una versión que hace lo mismo. Pero no es perfecta (es mejor que la función con `new Function` que tampoco es perfecta porque no detecta `global.window = global` ejecutado en node).

**Analicemos tu necesidad.**

Todo depende de cuál sea tu hipótesis de conflicto.

Si lo que se busca es detectar alguien en node que quiera hacer creer que estás en el DOM para falsearte la detección, yo al menos no le encontré solución.

Si lo que se busca es detectar lo mejor posible si es el DOM o Node, por ejemplo mirando si `windows === this` pero se tiene miedo que alguien accidentalmente haya escrito en algún módulo `global.window = global` para alguna cosa rara, se puede intentar borrar `global.window`. Van mis pruebas:

```
function isDOM(){
    try{
      if(typeof window !== "undefined" && this === window){
        if(window.window === window){
          try{
            window.temporarySaveWindow = window.window;
            delete window.window;
            if(window.window){
              delete window.temporarySaveWindow;
              return true;
            }
            global.window = window.temporarySaveWindow;
            delete window.temporarySaveWindow;
            return false;
          }catch(err){
            delete window.temporarySaveWindow;
            return false;
          }
        }
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }catch(err){
      return false;
    }
}

var isDOM2=new Function("try {return this===window;}catch(e){ return false;}");

console.log('isDOM', isDOM());

if(!isDOM()){
    global.window = global;
    Object.defineProperty(global, 'window', {configurable: false});
}

console.log('cheat isDOM', isDOM());
```

Answer (score 0):

Si nos centramos en el caso de browserify, lo que querés es un código distinto en node y en el navegador, lo cual se puede hacer especificando el valor [`"browser"` en el `package.json`](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#browser-field)·

La idea entonces es que en vez de escribir un código condicional, pasa esto si estoy en el navegador y otra cosa en node usando un código como:

```
function presentar_datos () {
  if (is_node()) {
    // magia en node
  } else {
    // magia del navegador
  }
}
```

La idea es que escribís esa función dos veces, en dos archivos distintos y usas require, y browserify te manda un archivo distinto en el browser.

```
# presentar_datos.js
module.exports = function () {
  // magia en node
}
```

Y haces una versión especial para el browser:

```
# presentar_datos_browser.js
module.exports = function () {
  // magia en node
}
```

Después en el package.json escribís:

```
{
  ...
  "browser": {
    "presentar_datos.js": "presentar_datos_browser.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Podrías detectar si está declarado el objeto `module` y `window` esté indefinido, debido a que si [tipeas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZoqvKTb) en la consola de node:

```
> typeof module
'object'
> module
Module {
  id: '<repl>',
  exports: {},
  parent: undefined,
  filename: null,
  loaded: false,
  children: [],
  paths: [ ... ]
}
> window
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Dicho eso, ya sea que decidas crear una función que devuelva `true` o `false`, tendrías una lógica como la siguiente:

```
/**
 * Valida que module y window existan para determinar true | false
 * @return Boolean
 */
function isNode () {
    return (
        typeof module !== 'undefined'
        && typeof window === 'undefined'
        && module.exports
    ) ? true : false;
}
```

Al final en tu código podrías tener llamarlo así:

```
if (isNode()) {
    // Código si sí
} else {
    // Código si no
}
```